Is it possible to change the site URL of a site created with GitHub Pages?
I currently have a GitHub pages site called username.github.io. Is it possible to change the username part to something else, but still keep the site up and in my name (profile)?
I saw this option on the GitHub Pages site repo:
Will changing the blacked out part (the username) rename the site URL? I've already changed the site title in the HTML, but I want to change the actual URL that you type in to go the site.
Is this possible? Is the above how you do it? If not, and it is possible, how?

It isn't possible. The name of the repo(which has to be public) with the site you want to deploy has to be the same as the account name.
